# Should I be using a FLOAT tag on DIVS with 100% width?

Tags: html, css-float

I have a page that has five DIVs stacked up vertically. Would good coding rules dictate that I assign the FLOAT tag to each of these DIVs, or is it really not necessary. I mean, it doesn't SEEM to present a problem (such as re-wraps) in any browser if I don't include a FLOAT, but I don't know what's proper in this instance.

Comment: Is their expected behavior to *always* be 100%?

Comment: Yes, always 100%, as they are merely wrappers for further content which will be centered on the page.

Comment: I don't see much need for a float. `display: block` should take care of it for you. Is there any particular reason you *think* you need to float these elements? A fiddle might help you get a more definitive solution.

Comment: Well admittedly, I have a long way to go in the realm of web page coding, and I wanted to make certain I was following proper code etiquette for this scenario, since so much is depending on my layout not falling apart at the wrong time!

Answer (score 1):

No need for a float in this case. Just use a div with display set to block.

```
.d
{
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}

<div class="d">
   ...
</div>
```

Comment: Not even necessary, unless the default style for `div` has been overridden elsewhere in the CSS.

Comment: True, but we don't know what his layout is like and I also wanted to let him know explicitly what a div should be set to for this behavior. I believe the implicit nature of CSS makes it difficult for some  newbies to get the hang of it.

Comment: To give you a precise idea, picture five divs 300px tall and 100% width, stacked one on top of another. This array is being utilized in a simple vertical scrolling page, where each DIV contains its own block of info.